# Why can't a set {(1,1)} be an equivalence relation of set A={1,2,3}?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I know that {(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)} is an equivalence relation of the set A. But I am not sure why can't the set{(1,1)} be an equivalence relation? 
I think it is because the equivalnce relation is specified for all (a,a) which belong to set A so elemnt 1,2 and 3 should all belong to the set and not any one or two(2 or 3 for example) only.Is this correct? (I am only taking pairs with same elements here on purpose to clearly elucidate my point).
What if I have to create an equivalence class such that neither a nor b is equal to 3 or 3 is not a factor of a (in (a,b) where both a and b belong to set A).
 Will such an equivalence relation ({(1,1),(2,2),(1,2),(2,1)}) exist or not?

Comment: it's not reflexive

Comment: What if I want to create an equivalence relation with my own conditions like a is not equal to 3. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Perhaps you mean something like $$\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,2),(2,1)\}?$$ That is an equivalence relation, where $1 \sim 2$ and $3$ is in its own block alone.

Comment: @amrsa how about in your equivalence relation, I put the condition a is not equal to 3, or a mod 3 is not equal to 0. Is it possible to exclude (3,3) from the set then.If yes, then will the resultant relation an equivalnce relation? Is it at all possible to create equivalence relation with our own conditions? Or do we have to first create all the equivalence relation and see what other relation they have apart from reflexivity,transivity and symmetricity?

Comment: @amrsa Does that mean that (1,1) , (2,2) , (3,3) are always pairs in a set being an equivalence relation on $A$ ?

Comment: @Peter Sure, by reflexivity. Each element must be related to itself. When presenting an equivalence relation as a set of ordered pairs, its $$\{(a,b):a\sim b\}.$$

Comment: @TanishkGoyal I think this completely answers your question.

Comment: @TanishkGoyal In any equivalence relation (as you hinted at yourself in the body of the post), there are always the pairs $(a,a)$ for $a$ in the set, so the answer to your last question is no, as it seems you already knew...

Answer (score 1):

Not only is it not reflexive,  as mentioned in the comments,  your proposed equivalence relation doesn't *partition* the set $A$.  That means that each element of the set needs to be in a unique equivalence class. $2$ and $3$ from $A$ are left out,  so it's not an equivalence relation.